# OpenOffice Calc - getting ### as the result to a formula

Tags: openoffice-calc

So I've got a spreadsheet with around 5 different rows, each one with a specific value (specifically a range of cells E2 - E8) and a "Total: " cell at the bottom, whose formula is this:

```
=Sum(E2:E8)
```

But when I enter the values, the Total: cell displays "###" as a result and anything that relies on the "total: " value does the same. I can't seem to figure out why. Could anyone shed some light on the problem? As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the formula, and the formatting of the numbers doesn't look wrong to me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's exactly "###" value in this cell? Usually "###" is the way spreadsheets display a value, which does not fit a column's width (and a value is OK itself; it's just  not displayed). Try to **widen a column** a bit... :)

Comment: WOO that fixed it. Thanks a bunch dude. I feel silly, though, didn't think to make the column wider, since it doesn't have a problem displaying text that's too big for the cell, it just marks the sides with red arrows.